# Neo4j query with more subqueries

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I was creating a query that could create a post and add image links, hashtags and genres to it but...

1. I'm not sure if it's the good way to do it like I'm doing.
2. My query fails every time MATCH doesn't find a node and that could happen often.

This is my code:

```
MATCH (user:User)
WHERE ID(user) = 611
WITH user
MERGE (post:Post {description: 'test', type: 'sketch'}) - [p:Post {date_upload: timestamp(), visual: 0 }] ->(user)
WITH user, post
MATCH (gen:Genre)<-[:IT]-(:GenreLang {name: 'Drammatico'})
MERGE (post)-[:HAS_GENRE]->(gen)
WITH user, post
MATCH (gen:Genre)<-[:IT]-(:GenreLang {name: 'Azione'})
MERGE (post)-[:HAS_GENRE]->(gen)
WITH user, post
MATCH (post)-[:HAS_GENRE]->(g)<-[:IT]-(r)
RETURN user, post, r.name
```

I create all those match merge with a foreach in Node.js, depending on how many genres or hashtags they give me I need to create more queries.

Comment: forget ID(user) node ids are no go for us dev users. Simply because ids may be reattributed. Use an identifier you master, never the node id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `MATCH` that fails to  match will abort the entire query.

Use `OPTIONAL MATCH` if you do not want that to happen. Unbound identifiers from an `OPTIONAL MATCH` that fails to match will have `NULL` values.

For example, your query could look like this (I assume that the first `MATCH` needs to remain as-is):

```
MATCH (user:User)
WHERE ID(user) = 611
MERGE (post:Post {description: 'test', type: 'sketch'})-[:Post {date_upload: timestamp(), visual: 0 }]->(user)
WITH user, post
OPTIONAL MATCH (gen:Genre)<-[:IT]-(gl:GenreLang)
WHERE gl.name IN ['Drammatico', 'Azione']
CALL apoc.do.when(gen IS NOT NULL, 'MERGE (post)-[:HAS_GENRE]->(gen)', '', {post: post, gen: gen}) YIELD value
WITH user, post
MATCH (post)-[:HAS_GENRE]->()<-[:IT]-(r)
RETURN user, post, r.name;
```

The APOC procedure [apoc.do.when](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_when_procedures) is used to determine whether the `OPTIONAL MATCH` succeeded before performing the contained `MERGE` statement.

Also, this query refactored the original Cypher code for matching the 2 genres into a single section of code.

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use the node ID, only use a key that you create and index. you can create an index and constraint like this.

CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (user:User) ASSERT user.email_address IS UNIQUE

MATCH (user:User {email_address: "joe@example.com"})

As for the matching. You can use OPTIONAL MATCH to match nodes or relationships without halting execution on failure to match.

OPTIONAL MATCH (gen:Genre)<-[:IT]-(:GenreLang {name: 'Drammatico'})

This will return NULL values if the match is not found, but the query will continue.